# Split details section into two individual vertical parts

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports

I want to split the details section into two individual vertical parts. Part 1 repeats data, Part 2 has statistical data. I want to remove the whitespace after each entry:

[image]

[image]

I tried formatting with multiple columns in the sections expert window, but I don't know how to use it properly. I also tried the underlay following sections, but it still shows white space after the 1st row.

Comment: any reason you are splitting the detail section... based on the images looks like cross tab will work for you.. it is just a thought though

Comment: @Siva  I need the data separated. The sample text should contain the denomination of the money then the quantity and the total amount.
How does cross tab work? I'm quite new to crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

If subreports are out of the question, the easiest way to do this is to change Part 2 into a Formula that changes what it displays based on the record number.

So long as you always have a minimum of 3 records (it looks like you could fit two lines per record) the data will display without whitespace. The formula would look something like:

```
If RecordNumber = 1 Then
  "Sample Text 1: " + {@Your1stValueHere} + Chr(10) +
  "Sample Text 2: " + {@Your2ndValueHere}
Else If RecordNumber = 2 Then
  "Sample Text 3: " + {@Your3rdValueHere} + Chr(10) +
  "Sample Text 4: " + {@Your4thValueHere}
Else If RecordNumber = 3 Then
  "Sample Text 5: " + {@Your5thValueHere}
```

[image]